# CSS - Show background image in li

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show an image inside the customized circular li. I just want to show a success tick image in that li. I have a CSS as -

```css
span.round-tabs {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}

li.success span.round-tabs.one {
    background-image: url('img/if_Tick_Mark_Dark_1398912.png');
}
```

```html
    
<li class="success">
  <a href="#" aria-controls="home" id="DivPatientDetails" name="PatientDetails" >
      <span class="round-tabs one">
          <i class="icon icon-profile-male"></i>01
          <h4>Patient's Details</h4>
      </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

But I am getting the result as:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp Most likely your image has some border to it. I'm sure it's a square image with a green circle in the middle. Offset the image position so the circles line up.

Comment: why do you assign the background to the span instead of the li?

Comment: You need to include bootstrap for your code to work in SO

Answer (score 2):

Either use

`background-position: center center;`

or use

`background-position-y` or `background-position-x` to position the image correctly.

Then you may want to make sure the size is correct using the `background-size` rule in CSS. If you post a jsfiddle, I'll be happy to implement this solution into that for you to see.

Comment: Correct, as long at the "content area" of the circle is 0x0, as it seems to be know. If that changed, it would probably not work anymore. As an alternative, it might be a good idea to use icon fonts, or SVG instead of images.

Comment: @omkarpatade Your fiddle doesn't look like your image, it seems broken.

Comment: @ProEvilz .. Sorry for that .. i missed d bootstrap part there .. please check this updated link .. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37286/